# DIV with an onclick function and an image inside of it has a dead spot

Tags: javascript, html

I have a DIV with in image inside of it. There is a spot right before the image that does not fire the onclick function when clicked. The rest, including the image and the DIV fire the function when clicked. I have tried attaching the function to the image itself in addition to the DIV and this does not fix the problem. Anyone know what to do?

```
//this give all the divs the function
var ButtonNumber = document.querySelectorAll(".ButtonStyle");
for (var i = 0; i < ButtonNumber.length; i++) {
    ButtonNumber[i].onmouseover = ChangeCursor;
    ButtonNumber[i].onclick = ButtonsAddTogether;
    ButtonNumber[i].onselectstart = function() {return false;}
    }
```

This is the HTML

```
 <div id="55" class="ButtonStyle"><img alt="1" class="Center" src="Buttons/7.png"></div>
```

Comment: Please share your markup/code so we can better troubleshoot your problem. From what you've described, it sounds like the "spot right before the image" either isn't contained by the DOM that has the action or is "covered" by another DOM with a higher z-index.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying a background for the DIV?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome but get the same results in Safari. I have set a background for the DIV. It is a gradient though.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image and the div to have the same height. That or use an inline element rather than a block element such as an anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

I have placed your code within jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BUwFP/1/

Please look at it and tell me if it works for you. I have just:

- defined functions that were not defined (probably you just skipped them showing your code),
- added borders to image and the div that contains it,

and everything looks fine - clicking the box etc. fires events. Do similar thing and check whether your box really is placed where you click or somehow it has been moved (probably by CSS styles or JS code). You probably already know, that you may use Firebug in Firefox, Developer Tools in Chrome or anything similar.

Comment: I can't find the bad spot on yours. I have a similar setup already. Accept my css is different. I'm wondering if that is the problem. I will fiddle with that a bit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, this may be issue with CSS. Using CSS you can change the location of the div, change its size etc. - thus it may be not in the place you are relating to as 'bad spot'. Just use Firebug or Developer Tools to add a border to the div and check whether it is there and what styles make it move from here.